# MS Bot: receive file via Skype connector

Tags: skype, botframework

Does someone know how to accept file received by MS bot via skype connector?
On bot side it looks like URL to files, but I need instruction how to authorize to access them:

```
Attachment: {
  "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
  "contentUrl": "https://df-apis.skype.com/v2/attachments/0-weu-d1-8ce3f64a740658ec8f227311edacc258/views/original",
  "thumbnailUrl": "https://df-apis.skype.com/v2/attachments/0-weu-d1-8ce3f64a740658ec8f227311edacc258/views/thumbnail"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Skype attachment URLs are secured by JwtToken, you should set the JwtToken of your bot as the authorization header for the GET request your bot initiates to fetch the image. See the following for some [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/662).

Comment: Thank you for response @Lars, it is very detailed ans how this thing actually works. But later trough the many tries and checks, since it is not described in bot SDK documentation, I found the solution which worked out for me and it is pretty simple one, just use HttpClient reference from Connector context like this:
`var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));`
`var content = connector.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(attachment.ContentUrl).Result;`
`var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();content.CopyTo(memoryStream);`